# Edge Critical Graph is $C_{2n+1}, n\geq 2$

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

A graph is said to be edge $\theta_0$-critical if for all $e \in E(G)$, $G-e$ is **perfect**.

"Every edge $\theta_0$-critical graph is $C_{2n+1}$, $n \geq 2$". This was proved in 1969 by E. Olaru.

Since this paper is not available online is there any alternate proof for this?

Comment: When is graph perfect?

Comment: A graph is said to be perfect if $\alpha(H) = \theta(H)$ for every induced subgraph H of G. $\alpha(H)$ is the maximum independence number and $\theta(H)$ is the minimum covering number of the graph.

Comment: Generally there are 2 type of perfect graph. 
1. $\chi$-perfect when $\chi (G) = \omega (G)$ for every induced subgraph of $G$.
2. $\theta$-perfect when $\alpha (G) = \omega (G)$ for every induced subgraph of $G$.
$\chi(G)$ is the chromatic number.
$\omega(G)$ is the maximum clique number.
$\alpha(G)$ is the maximum independence number.
$\theta(G)$ is the minimum covering number.

Comment: I suppose definition should also include that $G$ itself is not perfect.

Comment: Yes. $G$ is said to be $\theta_0$ - critical if $G$ is not perfect but $G-e$ is perfect for all $e \in E(G)$.